# Acumatica Load data from external REST service to grid

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project where I'm pulling in some external data from a REST API.

This is all working, but now I'm trying to figure out how to display the data retrieved from the API in a grid on a custom tab.

I created a custom DAC to represent the data, but I'm unsure how to get this into a view object that can be used with a grid.

I tried just defining a List object of my DAC type, but that did not work with the grid.

Any ideas how I can get a list of objects to display in grid.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a PXSelect variable and creating a view delegate to add the records to the view.